# Manipulate form data before it's sent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to encrypt some data in a form using jQuery before it's sent to the server, it can be a MD5 hash. It is a small project, so I don't really need to use SSL.

I have the  following JavaScript code where I use `$.md5` in the password confirmation info:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataToSend = {};
        dataToSend['action'] = 'signup';
        dataToSend['name'] = name.val();
        dataToSend['email'] = email.val();
        dataToSend['confsenha'] = $.md5(pass2.val());

        var options = {
            target: '#error', 
            url: 'insert.php',
            beforeSubmit: validate,
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function(resposta) {
                $('#message').html(resposta);
            }
        };
        $('#customForm').ajaxForm(options); 
    });
```

The problem is that the data is being duplicated. I tought that overwriting the data being sent by using the var `dataToSend` would make `ajaxForm` send only data in that map. But besides sending data from `dataToSend`, it also sends data from the form, so what I wanted to encrypt using MD5 appears both encrypted and clean. This is an example of what goes in the request:

> usuario=user&email=user%40email.com&senha=12345&confsenha=12345&send=&action=signup&name=user&email=user%40email.com&confsenha=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

I know I have to define the a function `beforeSerialize`, but I don't know how to manipulate form data. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't do that on purpose. I didn't realize I had to flag the answer as accepted. And when I did, it was just because I was very excited about solving the problem. I'll try to solve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation on the [plugin site](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object):

> **data**
>   An object containing extra data that should be submitted
>   **along** with the form.

The word `along` is the crux.
So when you pass data as a part of the options object that data is serialized and is sent along with any data/input elements values that are part of a form.

A better approach would be to hash the password value and assign it to the same field or another hidden field in the beforeSubmit handler(in your case the validate function) and remove the dataToSend object totally.

Something like:

Without any hidden element:

```
function validate(){
 //Other Code
  pass2.val($.md5(pass2.val())); 
}
```

With a hidden element in the form:

```
function validate(){
 //Other Code
  $("#hdnPass").val($.md5(pass2.val()));
  pass2.val(""); 
}
```

Comment: I looked up how to reassign it, but I couldn't find anything. Do you know how that can be done?

Comment: @AntonioJunior: Updated the answer with some sample Code. Chk it

Comment: Thank you very much, that does what I want!